# How do I create NIS groups with large userlists

Tags: groups, nis

I am trying to create a NIS group with a member list that exceeds 1024 characters.  Now I can't do that because the database that NIS uses restricts the value part of the key/value pair to 1024 characters.

The internet suggests that I should be able to break up the list and have sub-lists as members of the main list, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Theoretically, I should be able to go:

```
group:x:999:sublist1,sublist2
sublist1:x:998:a,b,c, [...]
sublist2:x:997:m,n,o, [...]
```

Then make and deal with nscd caches... if I then check a user account involved:

```
$ id
[...]
groups=[...],998(sublist2)
```

Since I want to use the group `group`, I should be able to go:

```
$ newgrp group
Sorry.
```

...but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to keep the `GID` that same for all the (sub)groups and have the real group as the first to be found e.g.

```
somegroup:x:999:a
somegroup1:x:999:b,c,d, [...]
somegroup2:x:999:e,f,g, [...]
```

Comment: You can assure that the ordering of the entries in a static file.  However, NIS/YP uses a database and the order of retrieval is not guaranteed.

Comment: @mdpc -- that would only matter if you wanted to list the members of a group.  I don't want to do that, all I want is for the group members to pick up the membership -- this is a stop-gap issue -- so this might work.

Comment: If the GIDs are the same, it works.

Comment: Also would there not be a problem with the newgrp command?  In that the user would have to use the name of the group where his username appears and not the "general" name?

Comment: Yes, you do have to use newgrp somegroupN to switch groups however the system will think you're in somegroup. It is a fugly hack but it works.

Comment: It is actually just the GID I care about.